# Как узнать результата кнопки поделится в Ok?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть кнопка поделиться в odnoklasniki, когда пользователь нажимает открывается диалоговое окно и нажимает поделится. Мне нужно узнать ответ поделился ли пользователь или нет. Вроде прорыл весь API, но таково ответа не дает. Кто что может предложить, как можно получить ответ? Если можно было бы ифреймить диалоговое окно, то можно было создать событию на кнопку "поделиться", но увы:) Можно еще без диалоговых окон, но не знаю как?\
вот код виджета может помочь

```
<div id="ok_shareWidget"></div>
<script>
!function (d, id, did, st) {
  var js = d.createElement("script");
  js.src = "https://connect.ok.ru/connect.js";
  js.onload = js.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") {
    if (!this.executed) {
      this.executed = true;
      setTimeout(function () {
        OK.CONNECT.insertShareWidget(id,did,st);
      }, 0);
    }
  }};
  d.documentElement.appendChild(js);
}(document,"ok_shareWidget","http://site.ru","{width:310,height:50,st:'straight',sz:45,ck:2}");
</script>
```

Comment: ` <div id="ok_shareWidget"></div>
<script>
!function (d, id, did, st) {
  var js = d.createElement("script");
  js.src = "https://connect.ok.ru/connect.js";
  js.onload = js.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") {
    if (!this.executed) {
      this.executed = true;
      setTimeout(function () {
        OK.CONNECT.insertShareWidget(id,did,st);
      }, 0);
    }
  }};
  d.documentElement.appendChild(js);
}(document,"ok_shareWidget","http://site.ru","{width:310,height:50,st:'straight',sz:45,ck:2}");
</cript>`